# Get specific message from queue(Rabbitmq) which is in json from a bunch of mesggae in the queue,python

Tags: python, rabbitmq, queue

Suppose I have two scripts - one is for cloudfront(cf),and another elb.I have some assigned value in json inside a queue(Rabbitmq), called request queue.when I run my elb scripts it should get only the msg with file_type=elb

```
{'file_type':'elb','elb_name':'name1','customer_id':'1','s3_bucket':'elb-logs-bucket'}
```

when I run my cf scripts it should get only the msg with file_type=cf

```
{'file_type':'cf','cf_name':'name1','customer_id':'1','s3_bucket':'cf-logs-bucket'}
```

My below code works only for the first msg I published to the queue, not type.Anyone can provide the idea what can I do to get **file_type=cf**  msg from cf scripts and vice-versa..I am using default exchange

```
import json
import pika
import logging

def get_rmq_request_queue(channel,connection,req_queue_name):
    payload_dict={}
    try:
        queue_message=channel.basic_get(queue=req_queue_name,no_ack=False)
        payload=queue_message[2]
        print payload
        print payload
        payload_dict=json.loads(payload)
        return payload_dict

    except Exception as e:
        payload_dict={}
        payload_dict['error']=str(e)        
        return payload_dict

main():
res_req_que=get_rmq_request_queue(channel,connection,req_queue_name)
    if 'error' not in res_req_que:
        s3_bucket=res_req_que['s3_bucket']
        customer_id=res_req_que['customer_id']
        file_type=res_req_que['file_type']
        cf_name=res_req_que['cf_name']
```

I might have many messages in a queue, the challenge is I need to get the recent message with file type...

Answer (score 0):

One of the points of RabbitMQ is that you can define queues to bind to exchanges with particular routing keys. You should use the `type` parameter as part of your routing key, then bind your queue so that it listens to the type you want.

See for example [part 4 of the RabbitMQ tutorial](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-four-python.html).

Comment: ..good suggestion..let me check..absolute new to rabbitmq..i will findout